# Strange behavior with nginx try_files. What's wrong in my config?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

os: debian stable (squeeze)
nginx: squeeze-backports 1.2.1-2~bpo60+1

try_files just behave strange to me.

this works as expected, $uri is tried localy if not found -> the @static location is used

```
try_files  $uri $uri/ @static;
```

just adding a =404 to the end leads to a 404. shouldn't it still work if i access a existing file which is located $uri or @static, and only serve a 404 if nothing is found on the @static location?

```
try_files  $uri $uri/ @static =404;
```

putting the =404 before the @static makes it *work* again. why? 
if the file is not located at the $uri or $uri/ location but on @static it should lead to 404 because =404 is befor the @static (for my understanding). if i put access a file which is located at $uri it is correctly served from nginx (not hitting the @static backend or the =404)

```
try_files  $uri $uri/ =404 @static ;
```

i am quite confused

edit: my goal would be: test if the file is locally, then check all upstream servers for the file and if not found on these locations return a 404

config:

```
upstream domain.com_upstream
{
    server yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:8000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=3s;
    server zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz:8020 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=3s;
}

server 
{
    server_name         www.domain.com;

    listen              xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;

    location @static
    {
        proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
        proxy_intercept_errors    on;
        proxy_next_upstream       http_404 error timeout invalid_header;

        proxy_pass                  http://domain.com_upstream;
        proxy_redirect              off;
        proxy_set_header            Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size        10m;
        client_body_buffer_size     128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout       10;
        proxy_send_timeout          120;
        proxy_read_timeout          120;

        proxy_buffers 8 16k;
        proxy_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    location ~ ^/test 
    { 
        root /var/www/test;
        try_files $uri @static =404; # exchange with upper try_file examples...
    }

    *** snip ***
}
```

Comment: What is the _desired_ behavior?

Comment: added the goal above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstood `try_files` parameters.  Quote from [docs](http://nginx.org/r/try_files):

> If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified by the last parameter is made.

Only the last parameter is a fallback URI (or a named location, or a code), all other parameters are files to test.  I.e.

```
try_files /file1 /file2 /file3 ... @fallback;
```

will check for files under the document root (/file1, /file2, /file3 and so on), and if nothing found nginx will do an internal redirect to a @fallback.

The `try_files ... @static =404;` doesn't really make sense as it will test for a file named `@static` under the document root, and most likely it's not what you want.  The `try_files ... =404 @static;` doesn't make sense, too, as it will test for a file named `=404`.

See here for docs: http://nginx.org/r/try_files.

Answer (score 3):

**for completness (answer from kolbyjack @ irc #nginx):**

**kolbyjack**: You only get one fallback. Whichever of @static or =404 is first is tested for existence as a file.
which will fail, and nginx moves on to the fallback

**c33s**: i am not sure i understand, if i define multiple try_file options they 
are not tested from left to right?

**kolbyjack**: Right, but all except the last are tested as files on disk.
So try_files $uri @static =404; looks for $document_root$uri, then $document_root@static, and if neither of those exist, then is issues a 404. try_files $uri =404 @static looks for $document_root$uri, then $document_root=404, and if neither of those exist, internally redirects to @static

**c33s**: so if @static is not a location on the local filesystem it only makes sense as last option?

**kolbyjack**: Correct
Everything but the last arg should be things you want to test for existence on disk

**c33s**: do you want to answer on serverfault to get the rep? if not i would copy your answer to serverfault and answer my question myself...

**kolbyjack**:  Go ahead, I'm too busy